# Stop debugger on current line of code being executed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

So here I am trying to debug this issue where the program takes forever to run and I can't figure out where to put the breakpoint in code because there are 1 million events firing.

Is there a way in visual studio to just stop on the current line of code being executed without setting a breakpoint?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, hit the Pause button on the toolbar and it will break at the current line.

Another option if the Pause button is not visible is to go to Debug -> Break All.

Comment: Sometimes after pressing the Pause button, Visual Studio will gray out the pause button and does not do anything - it is only possible to completely stop the debugging.