# Find the mutex my application is contending for

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, mutex

I have run my application and profiled it it using "INSTRUMENTED" mode and found that most time is spent on "Sleep", and so understood that it is a resource issue(it is a multi-threaded program).

So, I profiled it using using "CONCURRENCY" mode. I have both the vsp files.

Is there some way I can find out which mutex it was waiting for while "sleeping"? Or can someone suggest me ways I can make my application not spend time on sleeping. I am not sure what I must do now to make my application better. Also my application is pretty huge(maybe around 50,000 lines of code) and so I cant simply guess on which mutex it would have waited for.

Please give me suggestions I can follow to make this situation better.

Comment: [Concurrency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264994.aspx#concurrency). Resource contention profiling collects detailed call stack information every time that competing threads are forced to wait for access to a shared resource. Resource contention reports display the total number of contentions and the total time that was spent waiting for a resource for the modules, functions, **source code lines**, and instructions in which the waiting occurred.

Comment: Also, ***suggest me ways I can make my application not spend time on sleeping***, for this you will first need to know why the application used mutex in first place. Normally, Mutex will be used when access to a shared resource (like global variable etc,.) is required.

Comment: Start your application in debugger an break when you think it is in "sleep". Then you can analyze stack traces of all threads and find out exactly where are they waiting and for which mutex.

Comment: @sameerkn Thanks for that.

Comment: @sameerkn Thanks for that. Yes, it does modify a database and it locks hence

Comment: @BJovke : Can I set a break point on the sleep, instead of  guessing when its sleeping, and then see the stack and find the mutex?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood you properly.
Any process/thread which calls system timing/waiting functions will go to sleep until some condition is fulfilled.
If you already know where in the code sleep happens then you know on which mutex your program is waiting.
If you don't have many mutex locking places in your program then you can try to set a break point on each of them and then analyze the behavior.
Also, it might be that these sleeps are normal and that the program really needs to wait for some resource.

Comment: You can [pause the debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214355/stop-debugger-on-current-line-of-code-being-executed) which pauses on the current line. This is handy to fine things that cause bottlenecks, if pausing multiple times during running tends to take you to the same code. In this case, it will likely take you to the wait